# Make a JscrollPane's viewport size depend on the Scrollpane's container's size and layout rather than it's viewport view's size?

Tags: java, swing

According to the docs on how to properly size a scrollpane, says that the scrollpane's preferred size depends on the viewport view's size.

I am having an issue where I have a scrollpane with a JEditorPane inside of it. The default behavior here (which, in my opinion makes no sense if the JEditorPane is supposed to be "scroll savvy") is that the scrollpane expands its size so show the entire editor pane. Obviously this won't do, because I'm trying to layout my components to fit across the screen with equal size.

The below diagrom shows my setup. I am using MigLayout.

```
The entire structure is inside the bottom half of a JSplitPane, and is thus vertically resizeable.
--------------JPanel inside JScrollPane (Horizantal scrolling only)-----------|
| |------JPanel 1-------| |--------JPanel 2-------| |--------Jpanel 3-------| |
| | |-----------------| | |     Same as first     | |   Same as first       | |
| | |---Header Panel--| | |                       | |                       | |
| | |-----------------| | |                       | |                       | | -->
| |                     | |                       | |                       | | --> 
| | |-VerticalScroll--| | |                       | |                       | | -->
| | |   JEditorPane   | | |                       | |                       | |
| | |   inside here   | | |                       | |                       | |
| | |-----------------| | |                       | |                       | |
| |---------------------| |-----------------------| |-----------------------| |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

You can probably ignore the outer component. I'm just focusing on JPanel 1, whose height can change as its ancestor JSplitPane is resized, and the VerticalScroll component which should simply fit inside of it.

Simply put: How do I get the Vertical Scrollpane to fill all remaining vertical space inside JPanel 1/2..etc? I want the header to stay put at the top, and the scrollpane to resize its viewport *not based on its viewport view size, but on its parent container's size*. That is to say: no matter the component inside the JScrollPane, no matter its size or type, I simply want the JScrollPane to set it and its viewports size with respect to the layout of the container that its in.

I'm only focusing on the height of the scrollpane, not the width. That's a separate problem to solve which may or may not factor into a solution I find for this.

I've tried all sorts of things like attempting to calculate component height and position and setting the preferredHeight manually from there, but I always run into issues where the size grows indefinitly, or it doesn't fit perfectly into the container.

Comment: For some reason, your ASCII screen layout doesn't have a scroll bar in my display.   Create each `JPanel` in a separate method so you can test different layouts.  I'd use a `BorderLayout` for `JPanel 1`, with the header `JPanel` in NORTH, and the `JScrollPane` with the `JEditorPane` in the CENTER.  Your total display looks really busy to me with way too many components.  I hope you aren't confusing users.

Comment: Maybe also have a look at [`Scrollable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/Scrollable.html)

Comment: *I'm trying to layout my components to fit across the screen with equal size.* - sounds like a GridLayout to me. With the inner panels using a BorderLaout. *I am using MigLayout.* - I fond it easier to use nest panels with a appropriate layout manager rather than using a single layout manager.

Answer (score 1):

MigLayout doesn’t seem like the best solution to this.  It may be that MigLayout *can* do it, but I doubt it can do it cleanly or easily.

As others have pointed out, you can simply nest different layouts.  This is a very common practice, because it is how layouts are meant to be used.

In each panel, you have a resizable, scrollable component: the JEditorPane.  That should be the center of a BorderLayout, so it can resize when the parent panel is resized.  I’m guessing the header does not need to change size, so it should be in the PAGE_START (that is, NORTH, in Latin locales) section of the BorderLayout.

Then, place all three panels into a GridLayout, to force them to be the same size.

Here is how I did it:

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URI;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;

import javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument;

public class TripleEditorPanes {
    private JEditorPane editorPane1;
    private JEditorPane editorPane2;
    private JEditorPane editorPane3;

    private JComponent buildEditorPanel(String title,
                                        ZonedDateTime date,
                                        JEditorPane editor) {

        JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel("Name: " + title);
        JLabel dateLabel = new JLabel(String.format("Date: %tc", date));

        JComponent header = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 6));
        header.add(titleLabel);
        header.add(dateLabel);
        header.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(6, 6, 12, 6));

        JScrollPane editorScrollPane = new JScrollPane(editor);

        JComponent editorPanel = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
        editorPanel.add(editorScrollPane, "editor");
        // Make editor's default size equivalent to 20 columns by 12 rows.
        editorPanel.add(new JScrollPane(new JTextArea(12, 20)), "sizer");

        JComponent panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(header, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        panel.add(editorPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        return panel;
    }

    private JEditorPane createEditorPane(URL url)
    throws IOException {
        JEditorPane editorPane = new JEditorPane();
        editorPane.setContentType("text/html");
        editorPane.setEditable(false);

        AbstractDocument doc = (AbstractDocument)
            editorPane.getEditorKit().createDefaultDocument();

        doc.setAsynchronousLoadPriority(0);
        editorPane.setDocument(doc);
        editorPane.setPage(url);

        return editorPane;
    }

    private JComponent buildEditorsPanel()
    throws IOException {
        URI page1 = URI.create(
            "https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/" +
            "java.base/java/lang/Void.html");
        URI page2 = URI.create(
            "https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/" +
            "java.base/java/lang/Runnable.html");
        URI page3 = URI.create(
            "https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/" +
            "java.base/java/lang/Iterable.html");

        editorPane1 = createEditorPane(page1.toURL());
        editorPane2 = createEditorPane(page2.toURL());
        editorPane3 = createEditorPane(page3.toURL());

        ZonedDateTime d1 = ZonedDateTime.now().minusMonths(6).minusDays(10);
        ZonedDateTime d2 = ZonedDateTime.now().minusMonths(3).minusDays(21);
        ZonedDateTime d3 = ZonedDateTime.now().minusMonths(1).minusDays(2);

        JComponent panel1 = buildEditorPanel("First", d1, editorPane1);
        JComponent panel2 = buildEditorPanel("Second", d2, editorPane2);
        JComponent panel3 = buildEditorPanel("Third", d3, editorPane3);

        JComponent editorsPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0, 12, 0));
        editorsPanel.add(panel1);
        editorsPanel.add(panel2);
        editorsPanel.add(panel3);

        return editorsPanel;
    }

    void show() {
        try {
            JComponent editors = buildEditorsPanel();

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Editors");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.getContentPane().add(editors);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new TripleEditorPanes().show());
    }
}
```

You may notice that I did not take your goal of a horizontal scrollbar into account.  Having one dimension’s scrollbar on one component while the other dimension’s scrollbar is on a different component results in an awkward user interface, which may satisfy the developer but is an unpleasant experience for the end user.  Instead, I let each JEditorPane’s JScrollPane take care of horizontal scrolling;  since all JEditorPanes are resizable, a user can always make them bigger to remove the need for horizontal scrolling.

If you truly feel the outer horizontal scrollbar is necessary, you will have to create a subclass of JPanel which implements [Scrollable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/Scrollable.html), as MadProgrammer pointed out, so it will always use the height of the containing JScrollPane.

Comment: *If you truly feel the outer horizontal scrollbar is necessary, you will have to create a subclass of JPanel which implements Scrollable* Maybe use the [Scrollable Panel](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/12/20/scrollable-panel/).

Comment: @VGR The idea behind this UI is that the JPanel's are dynamically created based on the number of files a user loads in, and they are intended to be a side-by-side comparison of data. The idea is to load a certain number of panels at a fixed width until a threshold is reached and there are too many to fit on the screen, the the horizantal scrolling will kick in with the components at their specified minimum widths. 

I actually was able to get the horizantal scrolling and resizing working with miglayout, but this part has me stumped. I will look into this solution on Monday, cheers!